# unable to install VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, failed-installation

Trying to install VS2012 utlimate RC, however I am unable to succeed as every attempt is stopped at the below screen shot...does anyone has the same/simlar problem?

So my installation stops here and does not proceed from this point...I have left it for 3 hrs now and still its the same....any thoughts, ideas will be deeply appreciated...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 is RTM now. All pre-RTM releases are now obsolete. So go ahead and download the RTM if you are an MSDN subscriber. If you are not you could download a trial and purchase later once it hits public RTM.

Comment: You can also install the 180-trial of RTM if you aren't an MSDN subscriber - then activate it once it goes on sale.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov thanks a bunch for the answer...I am not sure why some people in SO are so arrogant and would downvote questions, instead of answering...thanks again...

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: can you give me vs2012 RTM link?

Comment: @Amir, sure, you could download the Express Edition for free here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2012-express